# How do I keep all my regions collapsed when opening/closing activities?

Tags: android-studio, region

As the title says - I have some regions where its filled with many lines of code and I want to keep them collapsed till I manually expand them.

How do prevent Android Studio from expanding every region automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by going to `Settings - Editor -> General -> Code Folding and thereafter checking "Custom folding regions" >`.